# rails syntax for block in ternary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ternary

I have nested loop blocks in a view with a ternary in the secondary block. This throws me a syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ':'.

```
<% @teams.each do |team| %>
  some html
  <% @account.some_attribute true?  ? team.users.with_option.sort_lastname.each do |user| : team.users.active.sort_lastname.each do |user] %>
    some html
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a correct syntax for this or should I find another way ?

Comment: This is quite ugly, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarekLipka: I think he's trying to invoke the same block with two different methods, conditionally selected.

Comment: I need to invoke 2 different scopes in my block depending on the @account.some_attribute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should do something like following

You should take array of users in some_variable for ex:- `users` and then iterate loop over it

something like this

```
<% @teams.each do |team| %>
  some html
  <% users =  @account.some_attribute true?  ? team.users.with_option.sort_lastname : team.users.active.sort_lastname
   users.each do |user| %>
    some html
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I fixed obvious typo copied from original code in the question. +1.

Comment: if `@account.some_attribute` always return one of the `true/false/nil` you can change your condition to following `users =  @account.some_attribute ? team.users.with_option.sort_lastname : team.users.active.sort_lastname`

Comment: yes, this works. I didn't think of splitting the syntax. Thanks